# Is it OK to use numeric integer value as 3rd argument of DATEADD?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 1 
            THEN DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, GETDATE()), -8) 
            ELSE DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, GETDATE()), -1) 
    END
```

This returns the last Sunday. If today were a Sunday, then it will return the prior Sunday.

`DATEDIFF` always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function operates in a deterministic way.

My question is that - `DATEADD`'s 3rd argument must be a date. So is it correct to pass numeric integer like -1 and -8 to get the output that I have achieved? I know that SQL internal date is 01-01-1900 (for example: `SELECT DATEADD(DAY,0,0)`). So -1 will be 1899-12-31 and -8 will be 1899-12-24. But is the above formula deterministic and OK to use to derive the last Sunday?

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the better approach?

Comment: I want to get the recent Sunday. For example: for any date between 7 March to 13 March (both inclusive), it must return 6 March

Comment: _Is there a better way_ Use a calendar table - something that has been mentioned previously and which you have likely encountered many times when researching.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of any good reason to start taking shortcuts of using hacks to accomplish a programming task. Its going to be hard to understand, hard to maintain, and might break in future. Instead do it properly.

Here is one way which is independent of the current server value of `@@datefirst`.

```
select Today
  -- If Sunday, subtract a week. Otherwise subtract the day of the week.
  , case when [Abs].Diff = 1 then dateadd(day, -7, Today) else dateadd(day, -1*(([Abs].Diff-1)), Today) end [Previous Sunday]
from (
  values
  (convert(date,'06 mar 2022')),
  ('07 mar 2022'),
  ('08 mar 2022'),
  ('09 mar 2022'),
  ('10 mar 2022'),
  ('11 mar 2022'),
  ('12 mar 2022'),
  ('13 mar 2022')
) X (Today)
-- Normalise the datepart result to be independent of the configured start of the week 
cross apply (
  values
  (@@datefirst + datepart(weekday, Today))
) [Rel] (Diff)
-- Adjust back to 1-7
cross apply (
  values
  (case when [Rel].Diff > 7 then [Rel].Diff - 7 else [Rel].Diff end)
) [Abs] (Diff);
```

Returns:

| Today | Previous Sunday |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-06 | 2022-02-27 |
| 2022-03-07 | 2022-03-06 |
| 2022-03-08 | 2022-03-06 |
| 2022-03-09 | 2022-03-06 |
| 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-06 |
| 2022-03-11 | 2022-03-06 |
| 2022-03-12 | 2022-03-06 |
| 2022-03-13 | 2022-03-06 |

Note: While many of the datetime functions allow abbreviations of the units, for exactly the reasons I list above, don't use them. Use the full name so its clear to anyone looking at your query what exactly you are doing.

Comment: One of the problems of using DATEPART is that I do not know what the setting of DATEFIRST will be on the user's sql server.

Comment: OK, modified to be independent of `@@datefirst`.

Comment: @variable how did you get on? Did this solve your problem?